# Slider and its tooltip text in ExtJs are not visible properly with webserver?

Tags: extjs, browser, webserver, slider

I have executed slider in ExtJs with and without web server.

**With out using Web Server** (Directly open index.html file)

[image]

**Using Web Server** (Apache, XAMPP)

[image]

I have observed unexpected output when I run the application with web server.

- Slider edges are not looking good.
- Tooltip text is not visible completely.

My index.html file code is as below.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Slider Tooltip </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../extjs/resources/css/ext-all-debug.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="../extjs/ext-all.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="padding: 30px">

    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my `app.js` code:

```
Ext.require('Ext.slider.*');

Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.slider.Single', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        width: 214,
        height: 50,
        minValue: 0,
        hideLabel: true,
        useTips: false,
        maxValue: 100
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.slider.Single', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        hideLabel: true,
        width: 214,
        height: 50,
        minValue: 0,
        maxValue: 100
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.slider.Single', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        hideLabel: true,
        width: 214,
        increment: 10,
        height:60,
        minValue: 0,
        maxValue: 100,
        tipText: function(thumb){
            return Ext.String.format('<b>{0}% complete</b>', thumb.value);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you solve this? If yes post your solution as answer.

Comment: I have seen this Chrome but not IE.  I got around it by just putting a width into the tip.  It was a static width but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this css

```
.x-tip {
    width: auto !important;
}
.x-tip-body {
    width: auto !important;
}
.x-tip-body span {
    width: auto !important;
}
```